# Return a list of dictionaries that match the corresponding list of values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, this is my list of dictionaries:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'color': 'red'  },
 {'name': 'Bob',  'color': 'green'},
 {'name': 'Tom',  'color': 'blue' }]
```

Based on the list `['blue', 'red', 'green']` I want to return the following:

```
[{'name': 'Tom',  'color': 'blue' },
 {'name': 'John', 'color': 'red'  },
 {'name': 'Bob',  'color': 'green'}]
```

Comment: Sounds like homework. You should flag it as such, in that case.

Comment: This is not homework.  I just made the lists as simple as possible for better understanding.

Comment: @teggy - I edited your question to make it look better. I hope you don't mind. You can edit it yourself if you disagree with any changes I made, or if you just want to look at how to format code on StackOverflow.

Comment: @teggy: OK. Beware that simplifying the case can get you non-useful answers. :) For example, you have the same length ordering lists as dictionary lists, and no duplicate colors. If that was not intended, some of the answers below won't work.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a little naieve, but it works:

```
data = [
    {'name':'John', 'color':'red'},
    {'name':'Bob', 'color':'green'},
    {'name':'Tom', 'color':'blue'}
]
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
result = []

for c in colors:
    result.extend([d for d in data if d['color'] == c])

print result
```

Comment: I'd say simple and straightforward rather than naive

Answer (score 2):

Update:

```
>>> list_ = [{'c': 3}, {'c': 2}, {'c': 5}]
>>> mp = [3, 5, 2]
>>> sorted(list_, cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(mp.index(x.get('c')), mp.index(y.get('c'))))
[{'c': 3}, {'c': 5}, {'c': 2}]
```

Comment: Will get them in the order blue, green, red, which wasn't what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You can [sort](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) using any custom key function.

```
>>> people = [
    {'name': 'John', 'color': 'red'},
    {'name': 'Bob', 'color': 'green'},
    {'name': 'Tom', 'color': 'blue'},
]
>>> colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
>>> sorted(people, key=lambda person: colors.index(person['color']))
[{'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Tom'}, {'color': 'red', 'name': 'John'}, {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Bob'}]
```

list.index takes linear time though, so if the number of colors can grow, then convert to a faster key lookup.

```
>>> colorkeys = dict((color, index) for index, color in enumerate(colors))
>>> sorted(people, key=lambda person: colorkeys[person['color']])
[{'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Tom'}, {'color': 'red', 'name': 'John'}, {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Bob'}]
```

Comment: +1: the key= approach is intrinsically faster than the cmp= one (thankfully dropped in Py3!) and the colorkeys building is a worthy optimization -- so basically there's nothing left for me to add in a separate answer (well done!-).

Answer (score 1):

Riffing on Harto's solution:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> [{'color': 'red', 'name': 'John'},
...  {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Bob'},
...  {'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Tom'}]
[{'color': 'red', 'name': 'John'}, {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Bob'}, {'color':
'blue', 'name': 'Tom'}]
>>> data = [
...     {'name':'John', 'color':'red'},
...     {'name':'Bob', 'color':'green'},
...     {'name':'Tom', 'color':'blue'}
... ]
>>> colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
>>> result = [d for d in data for c in colors if d['color'] == c]
>>> pprint(result)
[{'color': 'red', 'name': 'John'},
 {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Bob'},
 {'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Tom'}]
>>>
```

The main difference is in using a list comprehension to build *result*.

Edit: What was I thinking? This clearly calls out for the use of the any() expression:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> data = [{'name':'John', 'color':'red'}, {'name':'Bob', 'color':'green'}, {'name':'Tom', 'color':'blue'}]
>>> colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
>>> result = [d for d in data if any(d['color'] == c for c in colors)]
>>> pprint(result)
[{'color': 'red', 'name': 'John'},
 {'color': 'green', 'name': 'Bob'},
 {'color': 'blue', 'name': 'Tom'}]
>>>
```

Comment: Cool. Wasn't sure if that kind of nested list comprehension existed or not!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop function:

```
# Heres the people:
people = [{'name':'John', 'color':'red'}, 
          {'name':'Bob', 'color':'green'}, 
          {'name':'Tom', 'color':'blue'}] 

# Now we can make a method to get people out in order by color:
def orderpeople(order):
    for color in order:
        for person in people:
            if person['color'] == color:
                yield person

order = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
print(list(orderpeople(order)))
```

Now that will be VERY slow if you have many people. Then you can loop through them only once, but build an index by color:

```
# Here's the people:
people = [{'name':'John', 'color':'red'}, 
          {'name':'Bob', 'color':'green'}, 
          {'name':'Tom', 'color':'blue'}] 

# Now make an index:
colorindex = {}
for each in people:
    color = each['color']
    if color not in colorindex:
        # Note that we want a list here, if several people have the same color.
        colorindex[color] = [] 
    colorindex[color].append(each)

# Now we can make a method to get people out in order by color:
def orderpeople(order):
    for color in order:
        for each in colorindex[color]:
            yield each

order = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
print(list(orderpeople(order)))
```

This will be quite fast even for really big lists.

Comment: It can be worth noting that this solution handles cases when the list of people is bigger than the list of colors, and also when several people have the same color. If this is a homework question (as I suspect) then this may not be necessary. But if it is not a homework question, and a question about a generic usecase, than this will handle those generic usecases.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
people = [{'name':'John', 'color':'red'}, {'name':'Bob', 'color':'green'}, {'name':'Tom', 'color':'blue'}]
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

you can do something like this:

```
def people_by_color(people, colors):
  index = {}
  for person in people:
    if person.has_key('color'):
      index[person['color']] = person       
  return [index.get(color) for color in colors]
```

If you're going to do this many times with the same list of dictionaries but different lists of colors you'll want to split the index building out and keep the index around so you don't need to rebuild it every time.